# Rails 4 Nested Attributes has Unpermitted parameter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my api model:

```
class Api < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  belongs_to :service
  has_many :statuses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :statuses, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank?  }
end
```

Below is my description model:

```
class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :value
  belongs_to :status
end
```

Below is my status model:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :api
  has_many :descriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :descriptions, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['value'].blank?  }
end
```

And below is my new and create action of controller:

```
  def new
    @api = Api.new
    @status = @api.statuses.new
    @status.descriptions.new
  end

  def create
    @api = Api.new(api_params)
    if @api.save
    flash[:info] = request.original_url + ".do?apiname=" + "#{@api.name}"
    redirect_to root_path
  else 
    @api.statuses.new
    render :new
  end


  private

  def api_params
    params.require(:api).permit(:name, statuses_attributes: [:name, descriptions_attributes:[:value]])
  end
```

Below is my new template:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<%= form_for @api, :url => commons_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, "API Name", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>       
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :statuses do |status| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= status.label :name, "Status",  class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= status.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :description do |description| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= description.label :value, "Body",  class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= description.text_area :value, class: "form-control", rows: 12, cols: 65 %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

    <%= f.submit("Create Data", class: 'btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2') %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", root_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>  
<% end %>
```

After I create new data.It seems like only description's value did not save to my data base. and find an error "Unpermitted parameter: description" in my console.

Any one know what happen?

Comment: I change it to f.fields_for :descriptions but also show error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<%= form_for @api, :url => commons_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, "API Name", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>       
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :statuses do |status| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= status.label :name, "Status",  class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= status.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= status.fields_for :descriptions do |description| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= description.label :value, "Body",  class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= description.text_area :value, class: "form-control", rows: 12, cols: 65 %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

    <%= f.submit("Create Data", class: 'btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2') %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", root_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help.